# json.simple: class cast exception

Tags: java, json

can anybody help me with the following error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.xy.paket
```

class is a class extending JSON and that is why I do not understand why a cast is not possible? If I print an object of class on my console, I get the same output when printing an JSON object. It looks like:

```
{"receiver":"server","sender":"client","payload":"bookID;bookTitle","action":"doStuff"}
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should not name a class, `class`.

Comment: this was just for illustration purposes. of course my class has a different name

Comment: In that case, I would recommend a more general rule of not using reserved keywords when changing names for illustration purposes in the future.  :) It makes things confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates that you are trying to cast a `JSONObject` to `paket`. For this to work, `JSONOject` has to extend `paket` (which I expect it does not). If `paket` extends `JSONObject`, then you can cast from `paket` to `JSONObject`, but not the other way.